# Does requiring a gem load everything, including things I don't use?

Tags: ruby, memory-management, rubygems, require, ruby-1.9.3

Assume `x` is a gem, that contains both `Hello` and `Goodbye` classes.

If I write a program that `require 'x'`, but only uses the `Hello` class. Is the `Goodbye` class loaded as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You include scripts or files, not gems.

With

```
require 'x'
```

you load the file `x.rb`. Which `x.rb` you load is defined by the search path, the search pathes can be modified by gem definitions (what you didn't use in your example code).

Everything inside the file `x.rb` is loaded. If `x.rb` contains other `require` commands, those files are also loaded.

Comment: Check out the [autoload](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.3/Kernel:autoload) if you wish to overcome this problem.

Comment: @AleksanderPohl That's not necessarily true, if file `x` has `Hello` & `Goodbye`, using one of them will still load both since they're still in the same file.

Comment: I haven't found that both classes are in the same file in the description of the problem. They are only defined in the same gem.

Comment: Thanks, I meant the question to be open ended for both cases. Sorry if  it wasn't clear. I posted a followup Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002405/load-only-what-classes-are-being-used-in-ruby